# How to create a custom svg.js element using SVG.invent()?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I just don't get it. [Documentation](http://svgjs.com/extending/) explains how to create a custom rectangle with rounded corners, but how should I create, for example, a rectangle with some text inside, just like this one:

```
+---------+
|         |
|  Hello  |
|         |
+---------+
```

Okay, it's pretty clear that I should probably create a `group` and then put a rectangle and the text inside it, but when I try do do this in some different ways, I get nothing displayed.

I'm trying to create something that works like this:

```
var draw = SVG('container');
var element = draw.customElement('hello').move(100, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To everyone who have the same question: i have found a solution. Here it is:

```
SVG.CustomElement = SVG.invent({
    create: 'g',  // (1)
    inherit: SVG.G,  // (2)
    extend: {
        constructorMethod: function () {
            // (3)
            this.rect(100, 100).fill('red');
            this.text('Hello').move(25, 25);
            return this;
        }
    },
    construct: {
        customElement: function () {  // (4)
            return this.put(new SVG.CustomElement).constructorMethod();
        }
    }
});
```

And here's the definition:

1. Here goes the actual **svg element tag**, not the svg.js abstraction. For example, the `g` will come out as `<g></g>` and so on. My solutions failed because of it.
2. Here goes the svg.js class to inherit from. The classes may be found at the documentation, for example, the group is [`SVG.G`](http://svgjs.com/parents/#svg-g).
3. I decided to put the constructor method right to the element, but that's not necessary. As the [usage notes](http://svgjs.com/extending/#usage-notes) says, *construct does not supply constructors, but rather methods that are likely to call constructors.*
4. Here goes the DOM manipulations needed to put the element wherever you need it to be. You may call any other method that you had defined. I use `constructorMethod`, but of course I may use, for example, `constructorMethod().move(100, 100)` or just `move(100, 100)` or any other regular svg.js element manipulation sequence as long as I have such methods defined.

Comment: Note, that `create` can also be a function which is executed. In this case you need to make sure, that you call the super constructor (of SVG.G) in which case the `g`-node is created properly. After that you can use it like in your `constructorMethod`

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment to the accepted answer here another example:

```
SVG.CustomElement = SVG.invent({
    create: function () {
        SVG.G.call(this) // call super constructor
        this.rect(100, 100).fill('red');
        this.text('Hello').move(25, 25);
    },
    inherit: SVG.G,
    construct: {
        customElement: function () {
            return this.put(new SVG.CustomElement);
        }
    }
});
```

Note that here a function is passed to `create` which serves as constructor for the object. In it we first call the super constructor to initialize the shape (creates node, set defaults...).
After that we can use `this` as normal